# Should I be worried about these insserv warnings?

Tags: apt, scripts

These 2 warning lines popped up multiple time during apt-get upgrade
Should I be worried if so what actions should I take ??

```
Setting up libcupscgi1:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up cups-daemon (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01activate-net-rt' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'activate-net-rt' missing LSB tags and overrides
Setting up cups-core-drivers (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up cups-server-common (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3) ...
```

Comment: You need to fix the LSB headers in /etc/init.d/activate-net-rt

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a scripting issue for the developers making their scripts `LSB Compliant`, See [here](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts). There it states that for a `LSB` compliant script it should:

- provide, at least, the following actions: start, stop, restart, force-reload, and status. All of those, except for status, are required by the [Debian Policy, chapter 9.3.2 Writing the scripts](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.3.2). "Status" support has been requested into policy, see [#291148](https://bugs.debian.org/291148) and [LSBInitScripts/StatusSupport](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/StatusSupport).
- return proper exit status codes.
- document runtime dependencies.
- [optionally] Log messages using the Init.d functions: log_success_msg, log_failure_msg and log_warning_msg (This would introduce consistent output in scripts, as requested in http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2005/06/msg00729.html

and should also follow [Debian Policy, chapter 9.4 Console messages from init.d scripts)](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.4)

So I guess that script isn't complaint with the above requirements and are lacking these headers seen in old `SysVinit` files:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```